# Group by in sql server and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have 2 tables
MonthTable and DetailsTable

MonthTable has

```
+--------+--------+
| MName  |  MNo   |
+--------+--------+
| Jan-20 | 202001 |
| Feb-20 | 202002 |
| Mar-20 | 202003 |
| Apr-20 | 202004 |
+--------+--------+
```

DetailsTable has

```
+-----+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Did | DCategory |   Ddate    | MonthofDdate |
+-----+-----------+------------+--------------+
| A1  | B1        | 18-03-2020 |       202003 |
| A2  | B2        | 16-04-2020 |       202004 |
| A3  | B3        | 01-04-2020 |       202004 |
| A2  | B4        | 26-03-2020 |       202003 |
| A1  | B5        | 07-03-2020 |       202003 |
| A1  | B6        | 09-04-2020 |       202004 |
+-----+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

I dont have data for jan and feb months.

I need to join these tables and group by Did and Ddate or Monthofddate.

I tried doing but the problem I face is I'm not able to get any data for jan and feb! I did left join. 
I need a output where I can get 0 value for the Did for jan and feb months.

Expected output

```
+-----+-------+--------+
| Did | count |  Mno   |
+-----+-------+--------+
| A1  |     0 | 202001 |
| A1  |     0 | 202002 |
| A1  |     2 | 202003 |
| A1  |     1 | 202004 |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

and so on...

Is this achievable anyway?

Comment: Why you're storing `DATE`s like that? **Always** use the proper datatype

Comment: Don't tell me your columns `Ddate` is `varchar`

Comment: "I tried doing ... I'm not able to get any data".  Have you tried to write a query?  If not, then of course you are not able to get any data.  If you have tried, where is your query???  I don't see it.

Comment: MonthTable left join DetailsTable, group by Did, MonthTable.MNo

Comment: Here is a [tip](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00c7617180b96c59cfb85068283d3ba0) may be it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Ddate is not varchar

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense that you're not able to get the 0 for 'A1' records

You're trying to do a `JOIN` on a table (DetailsTable) which doesn't have a 'A1' record for 202001, 202002. So there's nothing to match, therefore you won't get a 0 count but a `null` value instead for `Did`.

Case will be different if your MonthTable table had the `Did` record.

What you could do instead is

`SELECT mt.MName, COUNT(dt.Mno), mt.MNo FROM MonthTable mt
LEFT JOIN DetailsTable  dt on mt.MNo = dt.MonthofDdate 
--     where dt.did = 'A1'
    GROUP BY mt.MName, mt.MNO`

If you still want to differentiate by `Did`, you can add it to the select statement and the `GROUP By`.

If you comment out the `WHERE` statement, you'll see what I was trying to explain to you.

I think you should be following the `Date` recommendations and also this is not good table design at all, since you shouldn't be doing `JOIN`s on `VARCHAR` variables